# How can I write a small log with bash?

Tags: bash

I'm running applications via PHP `exec` with bash. My problem is that this creates large log files. I need only the last ouptut I don't need a log of all activity per second.

This is my bash :

```
%s > %s 2>&1 & echo -n $! > %s
```

How should I modify to not append the output file, to rewrite it?

The full script is:

```
  exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo -n $! > %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

This is my full program:

```
$kovNev = 'uid1_fil_'.time();       
$cmd = 'btdownloadheadless --saveas /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/'.$kovNev.'/   '.$_REQUEST["torrent"];
$outputfile = 'downloaded_torrent/folyamatok/'.$kovNev.'.txt';
$pidfile = 'downloaded_torrent/folyamatok/'.$kovNev.'_id.txt';
exec(sprintf("%s 2>&1 | tail > %s& echo -n $! > %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

Comment: That's the greatest example I have ever seen here.

Comment: I'm sorry. What do you mean?

Comment: logs are good. maybe you should use logrotate instead if you are concerned about the big size of your logs?

Comment: I just need to know when X file is 100% downloaded via torrent. Than I would like to sop it, bit the latest screen , latest output would be enough. With PHP i cant handle 800mb big log files..

Answer (score 2):

`> $outputfile` does not append but overwrite the file. `>>` would append to the file. As you are using a shell construct anyway you may use a pipeline:

```
%s 2>&1 | tail > %s &
```

BTW: This works only if the paths do not contain special characters. The better solution would be:

```
'%s' 2>&1 | tail > '%s'& echo -n $! > '%s'
```

That prevents all problems except for ' itself in the paths.

Comment: It just gives me an empty output file. The path dont contains special characters.

Comment: @tigyijanos See the edit. I forgot to take the `2>&1` to the left side of the pipeline as it belongs to `$cmd`, not to `tail`. `$cmd` writes to stderr, thus the file was empty.

Comment: I tried yours with ' and without it, but not work. With it it writes: `sh: btdownloadheadless --saveas /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/uid1_fil_1370538091/   http://ca.isohunt.com/download/481427806/freeware.torrent: not found
`... Your second example gives me the error below. The first gives me empty file. (i updated question)

Comment: @tigyijanos Of course, '' may be around single shell words only. In your case it is a list. But I don't see a reason why the version without '' does not work. Does it work in a shell?

Comment: It don't work. I tried with this: `btdownloadheadless --saveas /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/uid1_fil_1370539958/ http://ca.isohunt.com/download/481427806/freeware.torrent 2>&1 | tail > downloaded_torrent/folyamatok/uid1_fil_1370539958.txt
` ... Just freeze my terminal..